# Optimising Solspace Super Search

Tags: supersearch

We have an EE2 on which there is a lot of content, there are several thousand entries, and within the entires each body field has 500+ words.

We are using Solspace Super Search, and results take 5+ minutes to render, I have looked in the documentation but I couldn't find any optimisation options, the only thing I could find in the 'Preferences' is the caching, which I have set up.

I've also added a from date, this helps immensely but obviously filters out older results.

Is there anything else I can do to optimise searching, placing indexes on tables etc, or limiting results by relevance?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the search terms and index tables in the db. They can get quite bloated (like > 1million rows ). Also, I'm not sure which method does it, but it runs an optimize table against it as well. Back in the day, we commented that out.
Working against that large table, can really slow SS down.